# Get part of string data with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table `Users`, where an e-mail stored (as string)
Is it possible to get only unique domains of these e-mails without any loops for all this users (e.g. using with LINQ)?

Comment: Also LINQ will query the data in any kind, probably by iterating your list. However without any code noone is able to help you. What have you tried?

Comment: linq internally loops through the collection, its just syntactic sugar

Comment: Are you talking of Linq-To-Objects or any database driven Linq provider which generates SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help

```
var domains = something.Select(e => e.Email).Select(s => s.Split('@')[1]).Distinct();
```

Comment: yes, but I think that domains will not be uniq and I must loop arund them and delete duplicates

Comment: if `Users` are gathered from db it will fail

Comment: **.Distinct()** should make it

Comment: @curiousity Changed the ToList to Distinct